# CNAME records and Heroku domains

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, cname

This is my first time setting up custom domains, DNS and SSL and I am thoroughly confused. I have a heroku app running on `sagerenewables.heroku.com` with an SSL endpoint at 
`okinawa-64385.herokussl.com`

My custom domain is `{www.}sagedataportal.com` and both are linked to `okinawa-64385.herokussl.com` in Heroku.

I have 3 CNAME Records(in Namecheap):

```
www -> parkingpage.namecheap.com
www -> okinawa-64385.herokussl.com
www.sagedataportal.com -> okinawa-64385.herokussl.com
```

as well as 3 redirect domains:

```
sagedataportal.com -> http://www.sagedataportal.com/
sagedataportal.com -> http://sagerenewables.herokuapp.com
sagedataportal.com -> http://okinawa-64385.herokussl.com/
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what. How are the CNN records supposed to look like? What about the heroku redirect URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to map `www.sagedataportal.com` to the Heroku SSL endpoint you only need 1 CNAME:

```
CNAME www okinawa-64385.herokussl.com
```

Assuming your current DNS provider appends automatically the zone name after the www prefix. Remove all the other CNAMEs.

As for the root domain (`sagedataportal.com`) the only way to map it to Heroku with SSL is by using a provider that supports the ALIAS feature.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain. NameCheap currently doesn't support that feature hence you will not be able to use your SSL certificate with Heroku under the root domain.